# JPlayer Media File Access

Tags: php, jplayer

I am working on music portal where the musician can upload his music.Music download passes through payment process.I am using JPlayer for play the music.

In `jplayer` anyone can see the path of music file with the help of view source and download file directly.

How can I prevent file from direct access.I tried to do it through `.htaccess` but the music could not play.

Why it doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?abc.com/trakvanapp/ [NC] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?abc.com/trakvanapp/.*$ [NC] 

RewriteRule \.(mp3)$ - [F]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be publicly accessible to play in jPlayer (or any other HTML5 audio player).  A rewrite rule won't do much good because then the file will still be accessible from the rewritten url (or if it's not, it won't work w/ jplayer).

The best solution I've been able to come up with is to obscure the filename in the script - very low tech, but it will keep 99.9% of users from discovering the direct url.  Lot of people are curious enough to view the source and look for a link, but if it's more complex than that, most won't bother.

so for a file at http://example.com/randomdirectoryname123/123random/mysong.mp3 I use:

```
var p1="http://";
var p3="randomdirectoryname123";
var p2="example";
var p4="123random";
var thefile="mysong";
var thelink = p1  + p2 + ".com/" + p3 + "/" + p4 + "/" + thefile + ".mp3";

...

$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:thelink
        });
```

Obviously this is not an actual secure method of delivering the file - just hiding its location better from Joe Blow.